# Swift crash while "downcasting" to AppDelegate

Tags: swift, notifications, crash, appdelegate, downcast

I am trying to get access the to AppDelegate from `NotificationContentExtension` like this:

```
private var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

I was thinking that the app will never crash, because it won't even launch without appDelegate. But it crashed and the console output is:

```
    Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 21734: (null)
```

Is it because I can't use a reference to AppDelegate in `NotificationContentExtension`?

Thank you.

Comment: If it's like app extensions I've used, you are not able to reference `UIApplication`. It's an "extension" to an *Apple* app (maybe in this case the OS?) and not *your* app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App extensions (including Notification extensions) do not have an application delegate. Also, they run as a separate process from your application and cannot access your application's delegate.